# How to raise Suds.WebFault from python code?

Tags: python, suds, fault, raise

I am trying to raise a Suds.WebFault from python code. The `__init__` method\constructor takes three arguments `__init__(self, fault, document)`. The fault has fault.faultcode and fault.detail members\attributes\properties. I could not find out what class fault belongs to no matte what I tried. How do I raise Suds.WebFault type exception from python code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer by chrissygormley works for me.  If it works for you, please checkmark it.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what exactly you are asking but you can throw a web fault using:

```
import suds

try:
    client.service.Method(parameter)
except suds.WebFault, e:
    print e
```

Comment: Not at all what's being asked for.

Comment: This actually is how you catch a `WebFault`, not how you throw/raise one.

Answer (score 3):

WebFault is defined in `suds.__init__.py` as:

```
class WebFault(Exception):
    def __init__(self, fault, document):
        if hasattr(fault, 'faultstring'):
            Exception.__init__(self, u"Server raised fault: '%s'" %
                fault.faultstring)
        self.fault = fault
        self.document = document
```

Therefore to raise a WebFault with a meaningful message you will need to pass an object as the first param with the message.  Document can simply be `None` unless required.

```
import suds

class Fault(object): 
    faultstring = 'my error message'

raise suds.WebFault(Fault(), document=None)
```

Comment: Great answer thanks. For reference I need to do this in a mock system to emulate a generic server processing error.

Answer (score 0):

WebFault is only meant to be actually raised when a `<Fault>` element is returned by the web server. So it's probably a bad idea to raise that yourself.

If you still would like to, I would start looking at the code where the framework raises it: https://github.com/unomena/suds/blob/4e90361e13fb3d74915eafc1f3a481400c798e0e/suds/bindings/binding.py#L182 - and work backwards from there.